R mediation with predictor and mediator as continuous variables and outcome as binary variable
I am running a mediation model using the r mediation package, and I'm not sure how to interpret the results.
In short:
Predictor = education (categorical, 1-3)
Mediator = income (continuous)
Outcome = mortality (binary, 0/1)
I have two models that are going into my mediation analysis (both of these run fine without issues)--
Model #1: linear regression examining the relationship between education (predictor) and income (mediator)
fit_indirect1 <- lm(income ~ education, data = dat)

Model #2: binary logistic regression examining the relationship between education (predictor) and mortality (outcome), while accounting for income (mediator).
fit_indirect2 <- glm(mortality ~ income + education, data = dat, family = "binomial")

Mediation model: Then, I put those models (outlined above) into my mediation analysis. I am using the R mediation package to run the analysis.
mediation_res12 <- mediate(fit_indirect1, fit_indirect2, treat = "education", mediator = "income", sims = 1000, boot = TRUE, control.value = 1, treat.value = 2)
mediation_res13 <- mediate(fit_indirect1, fit_indirect2, treat = "education", mediator = "income", sims = 1000, boot = TRUE, control.value = 1, treat.value = 3)

Output (for education level 3 compared to level 1):
Causal Mediation Analysis 

Nonparametric Bootstrap Confidence Intervals with the Percentile Method

                         Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME (control)           -0.00225     -0.00259         0.00  <2e-16 ***
ACME (treated)           -0.00137     -0.00160         0.00  <2e-16 ***
ADE (control)            -0.00561     -0.00582         0.00  <2e-16 ***
ADE (treated)            -0.00473     -0.00500         0.00  <2e-16 ***
Total Effect             -0.00699     -0.00725        -0.01  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated (control)  0.32261      0.25576         0.37  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated (treated)  0.19658      0.15332         0.23  <2e-16 ***
ACME (average)           -0.00181     -0.00209         0.00  <2e-16 ***
ADE (average)            -0.00517     -0.00537         0.00  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated (average)  0.25959      0.20454         0.30  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Is my interpretation correct:
The total effect of education level 3 (compared to education level 1) was 0.7% (95% CI 0.7%-1.0%) reduction in death rate. Income explained 25.9% of the education effect on mortality. The ADE (treated) indicated that individuals with education level 3, compared to those with education level 1, on average have a 4.7% reduction in death rate if income is at the level that would have been observed in the education level 3 condition. The ACME (treated) indicated that among individuals with education level 3, the effect of education on mortality that was solely attributable to income is 0.1%.
Is my interpretation correct? Would it be OK for me to conclude that income and education should not be included in the same model?
Thank you.

You didn't actually run a logistic regression model because you didn't specify family = binomial. Both models are linear models. You also requested no bootstrapping but the results suggest the confidence intervals are bootstrapped. This analysis omits an interaction between treatment and the mediator and assumes there is no confounding, which is incorrect. Your final statement doesn't make much sense; why would a mediation analysis imply two variables shouldn't be in the same model?

Hi Noah, thank you for your response. And my apologies- I inserted the wrong codes. I have edited the original question. Regarding your question, my understanding is if a variable is fully mediated by another variable, then only one should be in the model, right?
